# Implication for given statement

Tags: real-analysis, logic

Let $a,b\in\mathbb{R}$. Prove that $ab\leq\frac{1}{2}\left(a^{2}+b^{2}\right)$. My question: Is this statement equivalent to the implication: $a,b\in\mathbb{R}\implies ab\leq\frac{1}{2}\left(a^{2}+b^{2}\right)$?

Comment: Yes, it is indeed

Comment: Yes, and $ab\leq\frac{1}{2}(a^2+b^2)\Longleftrightarrow (a-b)^2\geq 0$.

Comment: Thanks for your help!